# Populate Android Listview with data extracted from a database

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie to Android programming.I want to use data inputted into an SQLite database to populate an Android Listview. However, Android keeps highlighting the SimpleCursorAdapter below as error. Can anyone help?

dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.secondview,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

Below is the full code:

```
package com.allmycode.databaseinsertwithlistview;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText GetName,GetPhoneNumber,GetSubject ;
    Button Submit ;
    String Name, PhoneNumber, Subject ;
    Boolean CheckEditTextEmpty ;
    String SQLiteQuery;
    SQLiteDatabase SQLITEDATABASE;
    TextView display;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListView listView;
    //Make these declarations to enable the fetchallitems() method work
    public static final String name = "name";
    public static final String phone_number = "Phone_number";
    public static final String subject = "subject";
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    private static final String demoTable = "demoTable";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);GetName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        GetPhoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        GetSubject = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
         listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListVw);
        //display= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView) ;

        Submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);



        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                DBCreate();

                SubmitData2SQLiteDB();
                displayListView();


            }
        });

    }

    public void DBCreate(){

        SQLITEDATABASE = openOrCreateDatabase("DemoDataBase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demoTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name String, phone_number String, subject String);");
    }

    public void SubmitData2SQLiteDB(){

        Name = GetName.getText().toString();

        PhoneNumber = GetPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

        Subject = GetSubject.getText().toString();

        CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot( Name,PhoneNumber, Subject);

        if(CheckEditTextEmpty == true)
        {

            SQLiteQuery = "INSERT INTO demoTable (name,phone_number,subject) VALUES('"+Name+"', '"+PhoneNumber+"', '"+Subject+"');";

            SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL(SQLiteQuery);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Submit Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            ClearEditTextAfterDoneTask();
           // addtoTextView();
        }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please Fill All the Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot(String Name,String PhoneNumber, String subject ){

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Name) || TextUtils.isEmpty(PhoneNumber) || TextUtils.isEmpty(Subject)){

            CheckEditTextEmpty = false ;

        }
        else {
            CheckEditTextEmpty = true ;
        }
    }

    public void ClearEditTextAfterDoneTask(){

        GetName.getText().clear();
        GetPhoneNumber.getText().clear();
        GetSubject.getText().clear();

    }
    /* void addtoTextView(){
         cursor= SQLITEDATABASE.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM demoTable;",null);

         if (cursor !=null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
             String name;
             do{
                     name = cursor.getString(0);
                     String pnone_number=cursor.getString(1);
                     String test2=cursor.getString(2);
                     String test3 = cursor.getString(3);
                     display.append(name + " " + pnone_number +" "+test2 +" "+ test3 +"\n");
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
         }
         display.append("-------------\n");


         } */
    public Cursor fetchAllItems() {

        Cursor mCursor = SQLITEDATABASE.query(this.demoTable, new String[] {this.name,
                        this.phone_number, this.subject},
                null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    private void       displayListView()
    {
        Cursor cursor= fetchAllItems();
        //The desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns=new String[]{
                this.name,
                this.phone_number,
                this.subject
        };
        //The XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.name,
                R.id.phone_number,
                R.id.subject,

        };
        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
        //as well as the layout information
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.secondview,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);



    }


}
```

Comment: what is the error shown?? any message?

Comment: and how your `SimpleCursorAdapter` look like?

Comment: The data from the database does not appear on the listview when I run.The logcat indicates that the simplecursor has an issue, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I mean that is the code for ur `SimpleCursorAdapter`? can u post it here as well?? Cause the problem is cause by the `SimpleCursorAdapter`,if u didnt post the code for this class,then we dont know the problem and therefore dont know how to help you

Comment: The simplecursor adapter is an Android API, which I imported into my code. You can see it in the import declaration

Comment: can change the `this` in `new SimpleCursorAdapter()` to MainActivity,this` ? and if cant solve ur problem,then what is the message shown by the highlighting error from Android studio??